# How to pick all elements but the one i hover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make all divs in a .html file disappear while the mouse is hovering on a certain div. In other words, is there anything like the `$(this),` but instead of this for all other divs that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var div_all = $('div'); //refers to all div
div_all.hover(function () {
    div_all.not(this).hide(); //hide all div's but not current one
    $(this).show(); //$(this) refers to current div and show current div
}, function () {
    div_all.hide(); //hide all divs
});
```

---

`div_all.not(this)` refers to all divs except the one which is hovered.

---

References

[this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Just in case, i would use: `var div_all = $('div').not(':hidden');` Maybe some non related DIVs are already hidden and then shouldn't be shown

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').hover(
    function(){ $('div').not(this).hide(); },
    function(){ $('div').show(); }
);
```